# How to truncate Magento newsletter template table

Tags: magento-1.9, php, newsletter

I like to delete the existing expired template in magento,i search the table in mysql, but i can not able to find the exact template table.

is there have any way to delete all the existing newsletter template query in magento.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `newsletter_template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open your database**

Find table **newsletter_template**

You can truncate this table. it is related to newsletter template.

**Note** : Please take database backup before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Open your database in `phpmyadmin` and run bellow SQL query

```
DELETE FROM `newsletter_template`;
```

**OR**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `newsletter_template`;
```